# How do I call a WordPress Category, using '$args = array ()'

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments

In the interest of making my code as readable as possible, I have structured some coding as follows:

```
$args = array (
    'type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset' => 1,
    'category_name' => 'news',
    );

$lastBlog = new WP_Query($args);
```

Does anyone see a problem with this coding?  For some reason, my 'category_name' argument is not being recognised and causing the whole code to not be recognised.  As a method of elimination process, I removed the 'category_name' => 'news', statement and the remaining coding then become recognised.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?  I have also tried targeting category ID but still run into the same issue.

Thanks.

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the category_name takes the slug, are you sure the slug is also 'news'

What happens if you use cat => [cat_id]?

Do you get the same null response?
Your offset is 1, is it possible you only have 1 post in news at the moment?

Comment: As a newbie to php, I have been getting 'stuck into' the code.  So much so, I failed to take a step back and look at the more obvious answer of ensuring the 'offset' was set to 0.  Thanks for pointing this out.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I guess that you want to get the last Blog post from the category "news", and I think that there is no huge question of your WP_Query args. And there are two advice:

1) Can you check your $lastBlog->post ? for example:

```
<?php print_r($lastBlog->post); ?>
```

What output?

2) Why you don't use get_posts function instead of it? it is easier to use than WP_QUERY for your question.
And the following is a demo of the function

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this expanded answer.  I have managed to solve the issue now, as per the above comment.  That said, are you saying that it is better practice to use 'get_posts' rather than 'wp-query'?  Would I be right in understanding that it is best to use the 'get_posts' function for the main 'umbrella' function and then 'wp-query' for all subsequent functions that create the loops within the main function?

Comment: Adding my 2 cents, which is by no means the 'right' way to do it. But I personally favour the WP_Query class in almost all instances. Check out this explanation which sums up my thoughts: 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755

When you get into more complex queries, and say have been used to using get_posts, you'll be less frustrated by the lack of control and possible arguments available in get_posts.

Comment: no, in fact, if you read the source code of the get_posts, you can see that get_posts use WP_QUERY class too, but it can help you to build the way to fetch the posts data more strongly and safety.